# Error FATAL_ERROR System.QueryException: unexpected token: 'CreatedDate' in a batch

Tags: soql, batch, query

I'm writting a query in a batch like that :

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.now();
DateTime trueDt = dt.addHours(2);
DateTime dtMoins1 = trueDt.addHours(-1);
String p = 'p';

String query = 'SELECT Id, StageName, CreatedDate FROM Opportunity WHERE StageName =:'+p+'AND CreatedDate <=:'+dtMoins1;
```

I run the batch in an anomymous window with this code (I don't think the problem come from here) :

```
Database.executeBatch(new myBatch());
```

But I got an error :

> FATAL_ERROR System.QueryException: unexpected token: 'CreatedDate'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed space between "+p+'" and "AND". you can use concatenation or field binding to get values from variables. but not at same time both
Should be

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.now();
DateTime trueDt = dt.addHours(2);
DateTime dtMoins1 = trueDt.addHours(-1);
String p = 'p';
String query = 'SELECT Id, StageName, CreatedDate FROM Opportunity WHERE StageName =\''+p+'\' AND CreatedDate <= '+dtMoins1.format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'hh:mm:ss\'Z\'');
```

you can use concatenation or field binding to get values from variables. but not at same time both

Comment: Thank you it resolve a part of my problem, because now it says "System.QueryException: unexpected token: '2017-06-06'". My query is now : `'SELECT Id, StageName FROM Opportunity WHERE StageName = :' + p +' AND CreatedDate <= :' + dtMoins1;` I don't see where I could have miss a space...

Comment: Remove the colon character before your date value...

Comment: @AdrianLarson it resolve a part of the problem too, but I got another error now : "system.QueryException: line 1:103 no viable alternative at character '<EOF>'" (it show the line where my query is)

Comment: @dou I've updated my post. That code works for me

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use dynamic SOQL in batch Apex (unless you have to). So in your case you can avoid the quoting/concatenation clutter (and mistakes) and datetime formatting problems and get compile-time checking by using static SOQL:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.now();
DateTime trueDt = dt.addHours(2);
DateTime dtMoins1 = trueDt.addHours(-1);
String p = 'p';

return Database.getQueryLocator([
        SELECT Id, StageName, CreatedDate
        FROM Opportunity
        WHERE StageName = :p
        AND CreatedDate <= :dtMoins1
        ]);
```

Comment: But in a batch the return type of the `start` method is `Database.QueryLocator`, so I'm not sure if I can do this

Comment: @dou My bad - I'd left the `Database.getQueryLocator` call out of the code; there is a signature that accepts a list of SObjects as well as one that accepts a (SOQL) string.